# test PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

I have a mail submission script that is working exactly as expected on both a dev environment and live with one exception. I am getting conflicting results from the mail() test conditional on the live environment vs the dev environment.

On my dev environment it redirects to $ThanksURL on success. On the live server even through the mail is successfully the script proceeds to the else statement and redirects back to the form page.

This has been driving me crazy so any ideas as to why would be most welcome.

Snippet of the issue:

```
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
            if($ok){ header("Location: $ThanksURL");
        exit;
}else{ $_SESSION['error'] .= " There has been a problems submitting your details. <br />";
                header("Location: $form");
                exit;   
        }// end if ok
```

Script in full:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$form = 'index.php';
$_SESSION['error'] = "The following errors have occured: ";

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    // Here 
$from = "Form Feedback <******@gmail.com>";
    $to = "******@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Competition";
    $ThanksURL =  "thankyou.html"; 
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $from;
    $attachment = 0; // is there an attachement
    //form fields
    $emailAddress = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
    //basic message info        
    $message = "Info submitted:\n\nEmail address: " .$emailAddress ."\n\nPhone number: " .$phone."\n\nComments:\n ".$comments. "\n\n";

    if($_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 4) {
         $message .="No attachement included";
        }else{
    // test file type and size for submission
    $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "txt");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES['attachment']["name"]));

    if ((($_FILES['attachment']["type"] == "application/msword")
    || ($_FILES['attachment']["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")//docx mime
    || ($_FILES['attachment']["type"] == "application/pdf")
    || ($_FILES['attachment']["type"] == "application/plain")
    || ($_FILES['attachment']["type"] == "text/plain"))
    && ($_FILES['attachment']["size"] < 2097152 )
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
        // boundary
            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

            // headers for attachment
            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

            // multipart boundary
            $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

                    // prepare the files uplaod
              $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
              $fp     = @fopen($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],"rb");
              $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']));
              @fclose($fp);
              $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

             $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$_FILES['attachment']['name']."\"\n"."Content-Description: ".$_FILES['attachment']['name']."\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$_FILES['attachment']['name']."\";size=".$_FILES['attachment']['size'].";\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
        }else{
            $_SESSION['error'] .= "Error: " . $_FILES["attachment"]["name"] . " is not a doc, docx, pdf or txt file or is larger than 2mb. Please resubmit <br />";
            header("Location: $form");
             exit;
             }
        }//file conditional 
     //prepare mail
    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
            if($ok){
                 header("Location: $ThanksURL");
                exit;
             }else{
                 $_SESSION['error'] .= " There has been a problems submitting your details. <br />";
                header("Location: $form");
                exit;   
        }// end if ok
    }// end sub

?>
```

Comment: location header should use the full URI

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you have a problem with something and you have used the `@` error suppression operator anywhere in your code, remove it. There's a good chance it is hiding a helpful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say this, but php mail can return something else on success than true or false, like mentioned in the [php manual comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#109655). Also, it is known to [return false on success on some situations](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=14032), too.

PHP mail() is a kludgy function from many different angles, and personally I would advise against using it in production systems. There are quite a few alternatives, such as [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHP mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html) etc.

However, if you want to use it, you should definitely log the actions and in this case, return values, and *not have @ to hide your return values*.

---

As a summary, in this case mail() returned an empty string, and not true or false.

Comment: Not to disagree, but it should be noted that the bug report you link to is from PHP4 and dated year 2001, and was also fixed in 2008 (wow, took a long time to fix!).

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes. There was no mention on the PHP version on the question, and there are PHP4 systems still running - it is possible that this bug is affecting, although I too think that it probably isn't about that. But who knows.

Comment: You have my upvote for offering multiple alternatives, and discouraging `@` error supression. I think the use of `@` is mostly by folks who don't understand what it does.

Comment: @WesleyMurch note also that the PHP4 part on the bug database is a bit misleading. The same fix was applied to PHP5 stream on the 5.2.7 version, as can be seen from [PHP 5 changelogs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) - so a PHP5 before that would be affected, too.

Comment: Thanks for all feedback. The mention of different versions of PHP got me thinking on the right lines. Somehow I had completely missed the comment in the php manual on this and the if($ok == '' || $ok){} resolved the issue as $ok was returning an empty string in the production environment. Point noted on the error suppression too. Thanks again

Comment: @ThurstyT great :) please mark the answer as accepted, if you feel like it did. Also, it is preferrable to use `$ok === ''` as `==` will evaluate some other values as true than just empty string.

Comment: also, if you have PHP that is of reasonably recent version, I would consider [opening a bug](https://bugs.php.net/) end to get this documented & possibly fixed. I didn't see there an entry for this case. But that's up to you.